# Array of NSManagedObject attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I'd like to get an array of the attributes for my `NSManagedObject` so I can use KVO to export them. I can create an array manually and then iterate through it, however, I'd like to get this list automatically, then iterate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An NSManagedObject has an entity associated with it. Use [NSEntityDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html)'s `-attributesByName` and `-relationshipsByName`. You'll get a dictionary back from each of those methods. Just ask the dicts for their `-allKeys`.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I added another tag. I don't see attributeKeys in the 4.1 SDK. Is this not available on the iPhone?

Comment: Correct. That's why tagging is important. :-) NSEntityDescription isn't as direct but it works well enough. Guess: The NSObject methods I mentioned appear to be there strictly for KVO magic, which is not available on iOS.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Joshua.  Here's code that I used in case any one would like to see a hard example:

```
NSString *entityName = NSStringFromClass([myEntity class]);
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [self entityDescriptionWithEntityName:entityName];
NSDictionary *attributes = [entityDescription attributesByName];
NSArray *attributeNames = attributes.allKeys;
```